# Is there a way to populate an entry box with the last saved file using python tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry, savefiledialog

I am a beginner to python and unable to figure out how to show the last saved file in the GUI using python tkinter.

Implementing the ability for a user to save their custom input into a csv file. I would like to after they save their file, to have the last saved file path populate in the entry box on the GUI.

Any ideas on how I can approach populating that entry box with the last saved file?

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried. That said, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example app that will call `asksaveasfilename` when you click a button, and update the text in an `Entry` widget if a filename is provided

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename


def save_file():
    if filename := asksaveasfilename():
        entry_var.set(filename)  # update the entry text


root = tk.Tk()
entry_var = tk.StringVar()  # updates the entry text automatically when modified
entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_var)
entry.pack()
btn = ttk.Button(root, command=save_file, text="Save")
btn.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()  # run the app
```